# Cant Resolve Android Dependancy

Tags: android

Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.*.*.
Open File
Show Details

Answer (score 1):

as shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack#installation) of your library, you need to add the library dependency like this:

```
repositories {
   maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6'
}
```

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6.

Could not resolve com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6.
Required by:
    project :app
 > No cached version of com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6 available for offline mode.

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6.

Could not resolve com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6.
Required by:
    project :app
 > No cached version of com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6 available for offline mode.

Comment: first of all disable  your gradle offline mode then to to build the project.

Comment: Error:(30, 20) Failed to resolve: com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.6
<a href="openFile:/home/ubuntu/AndroidStudioProjects/SwipePlaceHolderView/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>